# Firebase/Swift two database-connections

Tags: swift, database, firebase

I have an application where I would like to connect to two different firebase-databases.
I have two viewControllers  which are individually able to connect to each database, but if I connect to the first database, and afterwards connect to the other -  the app Crashes

I have 2 info.plist files and 2 ViewControllers connected with a button/segue.

[image: my files]

this is my first viewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var ref: DatabaseReference!
   var handle:UInt!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-anden", ofType: "plist")
    guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref?.child("UserVandreture").child("navn").setValue("Inger")
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
}
```

}

I can connect to firebase - which happens when I load the app.

Second viewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class AndenDBViewController: UIViewController {
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var handle:UInt!
let fileName = "Bambusstien"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
    guard let fileopts = FirebaseOptions.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
        else { assert(false, "Couldn't load config file") }
    FirebaseApp.configure(options: fileopts)
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    response()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//kan læse navn,type, længde og link
func response() {
    ref?.child("Vandreture").child(fileName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        let navn = dict!["navn"] as? String
        print(navn as Any)

        let type = dict!["type"] as? String
        print(type as Any)

        let Længde = dict!["length"] as? String
        print(Længde as Any)

        let link = dict!["link"] as? String
        print(link as Any)
    })
   }
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
    }


}
```

If I out-comment the database call in the previous viewController, this controller is also able to connect to firebase/database and read data, but if I don't outcomment this data, it will set the value in the first database, and when I press the button to go to the second viewController  the app crashes.

I have set the targetMemebeship for the 2 plist-files to the same application-name.
[image]

The error message says that the app has already been configured - however I thought that ref.removeObserver(handle) in ViewDidDissapear() would disconnect the connection to the database, before connecting to the other database - so what is wrong??

[image]

Comment: ups: i forgot to set handle to a value so...
var handle:UInt = 0
But the app crashes with the same message

Answer (score 0):

Basically i needed protection of my data, but I had not populated the databases yet so..
The solution to my problem was to work with the rules-part - having just  a single database.
Allowing users to have write-access to certain part of the database, and only having read-access to other parts  - something like:

```
{
"rules": {
"myPersonal":{
".read": true,
".write": "auth != null"

},
"myPublic": {
".read":  "auth != null",
".write": true

}
```

}
}